# Terraform for and for_each and templating

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to have an structure of variables like so:

```
variable "registry" {
  type = map(map(list(string)))
  default = {
    "container1" = {
      "roles/artifactregistry.reader" = ["user:jane@example.com", "group:devs@example.com"],
      "roles/artifactregistry.writer" = ["group:editors@example.com"]
    },
    "container2" = {
      "roles/artifactregistry.reader" = ["user:jane@example.com"],
      "roles/artifactregistry.writer" = ["group:editors2@example.com", "group:editors3@example.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

I do see there are questions/answers about the usage of `for_each` and `for`, sadly, I am not being able to make this work despite my efforts. Also, by all means, I want to avoid the usage of `count`.

Any help with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **flatten** your data structure, which you can do as follows:

```
locals {
  registry_flat = merge(flatten([
    for container, roles in var.registry: [
      for role, members in roles: {
        for member in members: 
          "${container}-${role}-${member}" => {
            container = container
            role = role
            member = member
          }
      }
    ]
  ])...) # please do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository_iam_member" "member" {

  for_each   = local.registry_flat

  repository = each.value.container
  role       = each.value.role
  member     = each.value.member
}
```

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you very much! Although the answer is accepted already, would it be too much to ask if you provide with a short explanation of what you are doing there?

Comment: @carrotcakeslayer No problems, the dots change `marge([a,b,c]...)` into `marge(a,b,c)`.